# Is there a name for the center of a line?

Tags: geometry

Is there a name for the center point for a line?

For example:
---------o---------

If the dashes represent a straight line and the O represents the center of that line, what would the name for that center point be?

Comment: basic intro to geometrical terms [here](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/geometry/hs-geo-foundations/hs-geo-intro-euclid/v/language-and-notation-of-basic-geometry)

Comment: Wow, I really forgot about KhanAcademy. I should probably start taking more notes with it. Thanks!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

A line goes forever in both directions, so it has no center.  If you have a line segment - a part of a line with two definite ends - then the name is "midpoint."

Comment: Thanks, this really helps!